# Pagination on a sorted list of entities from different sources

Tags: algorithm, list, api, sorting, pagination

My problem is that, I have two lists for, the sake of simplicity with 4-4 items, these are not unique items. The items sorted by a calculated value, let's call it rank. Now I have to display 2 items per page from the 8 items, but only unique values ordered by the ranking.

So I have this two lists:

**List A**

```
A - 1
B - 2
D - 5
C - 6
```

**List B**

```
A - 2
D - 3
B - 4
C - 5
```

So, I need the first page of items ordered by the ranking with offset 0 limit 2 and that would be:

**First page**

```
A(list A) - 1
B(list A) - 2 // we skip the A from list B because we need unique values
```

so the second page is expected to be:

**Expected 2nd page**

```
D(list B) - 3
C(list B) - 5
```

but the actual second page, because of the offset (skips the first two items in each list), would result:

**Actual 2nd page**

```
B(list B) - 4
D(list A) - 5 // or C - 5 from list B
```

values would be duplicated (B), which is obviously bad.

Now the only solution I can think of is to merge all the lists into one ordered list and apply the pagination on that list, but this is something that I can't do. I access these lists through an API and even it is an in-house API I have to think of this as a 3rd party API what can not be changed. The API accepts only sort direction (asc, desc), offset and limit parameters.

I should display these values in real time, if something changed in the lists, I have to show those changes.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you expose the relevant parts of the API?

Comment: Is it a web application?

Comment: Yes, it is a web application. What would you like to see about the API? The interface is pretty simple, /list/:listid/offset/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort, this is all I can play around with. It returns an array in json with the items. @Tarik

Comment: Do you have to get all of the items in one shot in the JSON structure? If so, how big is it?

Comment: I can get the lists in pieces. Currently the lists aren't too big, few 1-2k items per list, but they can grow to "infinity".

Answer (score 1):

I have one idea. Please review it.

Assumption made:
Both list have equal entries.

Here is the sample code that will solve your problem:

```
node * H_A = List_A.head
node * H_B = List_B.head

while ((H_A == NULL) || (H_B == NULL))
{
    // Here I am maintaining an invariant that value pointed by H_B is
    // greater than the value pointed by H_A.
    if (H_B > H_A)
    {
        swap (H_B, H_A);
    }

    Display value of H_A on the current page. This is the first value of the page.

    Move H_A to next value.

    if (value.H_B > value.H_A)
    {
        Display value of H_A on the current page. This is the second value of the page.
    }
    else
    {
        Display value of H_B on the current page. This is the second value of the page.
    }

    Move H_A to next value.
    Move H_B by two values.
    Move to next page. This page is completed.
}
```

Please let me know, if it does not solve your problem. We will work on that.